# Get items from json data and add to array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am using the Flickr api to retrieve images based on a search using the following code. The function sends the image id to the endpoint and returns an object which I parse to get a specific url for said image. I get the response that I want but I am trying to get all the image urls which are in `item.source` and add them to an array. I have tried returning a array but the compiler complains this cannot be done as it's a `non-void return from a void method` despite me setting `[String]` as the return. How can I get the list of `item.source` as an array to be used outside of `getURLImages()`? Alternatively, I have created urlsList as below, and tried to append the `item.source` to this but this always prints as empty. For context, I am planning to create a `UICollectionView` to display said images/urls.

**UPDATE**

Below is the function from class A that calls getURLImages from class B:

```
 let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
  
 if (result.stat == "ok"){
     for urls in result.photos!.photo {           
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
             GetImageInfo().getURLImages(photoId: urls.id) { urlsList in
                  print("Received \(urlsList)")
              }
         }
      }
 }
```

Below is the function from class B:

```
let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
var urlList = [String]()
for item in result.sizes!.size {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if (item.label == "Square"){
            urlList.append(item.source)
                            
        }
    }
 }
 completion(urlList)
```

How can I access the urlsList property outside the scope of the functions so that it can be implemented into a UICollectionView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly return a value for a function from a closure. You will have to use completion handler closure for this.

---

Example:

```
func getURLImages(photoId: String, completion: @escaping ([String]) -> Void) {
    ...
    // Call completion handler when you generate your [String] response
    completion(yourImageURLs)
    ...
}
```

---

And use it like this:

```
let urls = [String]()

getURLImages(photoId: "some id") { [weak self] imageURLs in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    print("Received some \(imageURLs)"
    self.urls = imageURLs
    self.updateCollectionViewOrSomething()
}

func updateCollectionViewOrSomething() {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Inside the function, what would I replace yourImageURLS with? They're currently obtained once looping through the json response and where a specific key,value occurs. Would I do completion(urlsList)?

Comment: You could create a local `[String]` array inside your closure before starting your for loop and populate that array instead of `urlsList`, then use that array inside a completion instead. That way you could easily move your `getURLImages` somewhere else without breaking your code that much.

Comment: And to even more isolate your function from outside you could improve your parameters list: `getURLImages(photoId: String, config: AppConfig = AppConfig(), completion: ...)`

Comment: This way you could move `getURLImages` into its separate file or anywhere else in the codebase without breaking your existing code.

Comment: By the way, completion handler should be called when you FINISH gathering your urls, so, outside the for loop.

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there a way for me to use the result of urlsList outside the scope of where I call the function? Because that function call is actually nested in its its own endpoint search. The plan is to create a collection view so how would I access this var? I have updated my code in the question

Comment: Yes there is a way. Make your collection view depend on data from `urlList` and when you receive a value from completion handler, update that list and call a function that updates collection view `collectionView.reloadData()` or something.

Comment: @Nouman Updated the answer to make things more clear

Comment: Thank you! @Tomas for your answer